# Traversing through IGraphServiceCollectionPage

Tags: .net, if-statement, microsoft-graph-api, traversal

I have made a List of graph service collection page but I need to put if loop to see if email exits in the list.
Can someone help me t traverse.
This is the code

var authProvider = await GetAuthProvider();

```
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);


            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
            users.AddRange(user.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
            
            while (user.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                user = await user.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                users.AddRange(user.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
                
            }
```

I want to know if the string {email} exits in users if yes return true if not return exception. but cannot convert as getting error **cannot convert type string to Users**

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it doesn't contain email you have to go 1 level down. if you want to get the mail you need to use Messages.

This is the demo API to get emails in graph explorer - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser) ID}/messages

The best way is to debug your code.